# Expect, Bash and kpcli

Tags: bash, shell, expect

I have written a script which connects to a local keepass db using kpcli and expect, gets the credentials out of the database and then connects via ssh. The script works but after logging in successfully to the remote host via SSH the session dies after about 5 seconds.

```
 #!/bin/bash

 firewall="$1"
 keepass_password="******"
 keepass_db="/media/sf_VM_shared/kdb.kdb"
 keepass_fw_dir="General/Network/Firewalls/SSH"
 firewall_user="admin"


echo -e "\n"
echo "Connecting to keepass Database..."

function get_creds {
  expect <<- DONE
     set timeout 10
     spawn kpcli
     match_max 100000000
     expect  "kpcli:/>"
     send    "open $keepass_db\n"
     expect  "password:"
     send    "$keepass_password\n"
     expect  ">"
     send    "cd $keepass_fw_dir\n"
     expect  "SSH>"
     send    "show -f $firewall\n"
     expect  ">"
DONE

}

credentials=$(get_creds)
ssh_info=$(echo "$credentials" | grep 'Title:\|Pass:\|Notes:' | sed -e 's/^.*:       //')
ip_address=$(echo "$ssh_info" | awk 'NR==3')
firewall_name=$(echo "$ssh_info" | awk 'NR==1')
firewall_pass=$(echo "$ssh_info" | awk 'NR==2')
echo -e "\n"
echo "------Firewall Information-------"
echo -e Firewall IP:'\t \t'         "$ip_address"
echo -e Firewall Name:'\t \t'           "$firewall_name"
echo -e Firewall Password:'\t'          "$firewall_pass"
echo "----------------------------------"
echo -e "\n"
echo "Connecting to firewall module with user "admin"..."

function ssh_connect {
expect <<- DONE
spawn ssh -v -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no admin@$ip_address
expect  "password"
      sleep 5
      send  "$firewall_pass\n"
      expect continue
      expect eof

DONE
}

ssh_connect
```

Comment: Having a bunch of `echo "$foo" | awk` lines is silly when bash itself can extract those things trivially (and more efficiently) with only built-in functionality. Consider: `{ read -r ip_address; read -r firewall_name; read -r firewall_pass; } <<<"$ssh_info"`

Comment: Also, `echo -e` is non-POSIX-compliant (see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html). Use `printf`. Also, avoid the `function` keyword -- it adds no benefit over the compliant function definition syntax, but makes your code needlessly incompatible with other shells.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Agree 100% but thought I should point out that your variable order was incorrect. The `NR` values aren't in order in the OP's code. The lines are `name`, `pass`, `ip` in that order.

Comment: Inexperience is not silliness. Thanks for the advice. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working with the following:

```
expect -c '
spawn ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no admin@'$ip_address'
expect "(password)"
send '$firewall_pass'
expect "(*)"
interact'
```

Answer (score 2):

I take it you're referring to your `ssh_connect` function, and I further assume you want that ssh session to be interactive once you've authenticated yourself. You need the expect `interact` command to pass control to the user.

```
function ssh_connect {
    expect <<- DONE
        spawn ssh -v -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no admin@$ip_address
        expect  "password"
        send -- "$firewall_pass\r"
        interact
DONE
}
```

- It's idiomatic in expect to send a carriage return `\r` for "hitting enter".
- use the double hyphen in `send -- "$variable"` to protect against the case when the first character of the variable is a hyphen.

Comment: Either this or a `timeout` issue. But assuming the code is complete this is much more likely.

Comment: I've tried to use 'interact' but I don't even log into the remote shell if I do. If I remove the 'expect eof' then I don't login to the shell. I just get dropped back to the local shell.

Comment: use `expect -d <<DONE` to get expect to tell you what's happening in the background.

Comment: If I use interact and remove eof I get :

expect: set expect_out(buffer) "admin@200.69.XXX.XXX's password"
send: sending "PASSWORD\r\r" to { exp6 }

expect: does ": " (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "*"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) ": "
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp6"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) ": "
spawn id exp6 sent <\r\n>

interact: received eof from spawn_id exp0